# Spring MVC mocking using mockito not happening on service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, junit5

Here is my Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class LoanController {
    
    @Autowired 
    private LoanService loanService;
        
    @GetMapping("/loans/{id}")
    public Loan getLoan(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return loanService.getLoan(id);
    }   
    
    @PostMapping("/loans")
    public ResponseEntity <String> addLoan(@RequestBody Loan loan) {
        System.out.println(" Test 2 >> " + loanService.isLoanProcessed(loan));
        
        if(loanService.isLoanProcessed(loan)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build(); //return http 201 return code
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build(); // return http 409 return code
        
    }   
}
```

Service :

```java
@Service
public class LoanService {
    
    @Autowired
    private LoanRepository loanRepo;

    public boolean isLoanProcessed(Loan loan) {
        // Validate the Loan
        if(isValid(loan)) {
            
            // Get the Loan Fee
            Double loanFees = getLoanFees(loan.getLoanType().trim());
            
            // Get the total Loan Interest
            Double totLoanInterest = calcLoanTotalInterest(loan.getLoanAmt(),loan.getRate(),loan.getLoanTerm());
            
            // Get the APR
            Double apr = getAPR(totLoanInterest,loanFees,loan.getLoanAmt(),loan.getLoanTerm());
            
            // Set calculate APR to Loan model
            loan.setApr(apr);
            
            // Add the loan to db
            this.addLoan(loan);
            
            return true;
            
        } else {
            // If the Loan is not valid throw custom exception
            // Still need to be implemented
            return false;
        }
}
```

Here is the TestClass :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LoanControllerIntegrationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private LoanService mockLoanService;
    private AutoCloseable closeable;
    
    @InjectMocks
    LoanController loanController;
    
    private Loan loan;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws Exception {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loanController).build();
        
    }

   @Test
    @DisplayName("POST /loans")
    final void addLoanIdTest() throws Exception {
        loan.setApr(Double.valueOf(5.15));
        loan.setLoanStatus("A");
        
        when(mockLoanService.isLoanProcessed(loan)).thenReturn(true);
        
        System.out.println(" Test 1 >> " + mockLoanService.isLoanProcessed(loan));  // printing true
        
        mockMvc.perform(post("/loans")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(convertObjToJsonString(loan)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
          
    }
```

Here is my question :
In the test, mocking happening correctly when I print on `mockLoanService.isLoanProcessed(loan)` value is correct which is true, But in Controller, post method modified mocking data is not picking, when I print showing as `false`, condition check on controller `if(loanService.isLoanProcessed(loan))` not happening using mocking data. Please provide your input where I am making mistake.

Comment: What makes you think it’s not working, because the assertion fails? You are returning HTTP status created in your controller, but verifying for HTTP staus ok in the test.

Comment: I want the mocking service in the controller loanService.isLoanProcessed(loan); controller needs to evaluated true so that controller should execute the return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();  and return 201. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are binding mock to particular `Loan` object created in `LoanControllerIntegrationTests` class. The object created in controller is not the same object.

Simple example:
[image]

To solve your issue, please use `any()` operator:

```
when(mockLoanService.isLoanProcessed(any(Loan.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

that you can obtain from following import statement:
`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;`

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. Then my next question how to get the controller-generated Loan object.

Comment: I assume you want to check controller response. To access response json use `jsonPath`, example:
`.andExpect(jsonPath("$.loanValue").value(123.456f))`

Answer (score 0):

in your before method, try adding:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Comment: init() method added closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); thought this is going initialize the mock.